# TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize) for my lexer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i am trying to make a lexer for my programming language called AJPS and i am struggling with this cause i suck with python stacktraces so can someone please help thank you  also it will be my dream language cause i keep switching from language to language for ex like i did haskell for a while then i did nim then i did f# then i did c then i did c++ then i did c#(I HATED IT) then i went to python then decided to do this

ajps.py

```py
DIGITS = '0123456789'

#########################################
#                ERRORS                 #
#########################################
class err:
    def __init__(self, errn, details):
        self.errn = errn
        self.details = details

    def as_string(self):
        result = f'{self.errn}: {self.details}'
        return result

class unExChar:
    def __init__(self, details):
        super().__init__('AJPS DOES NOT UNDERSTAND CHAR AT', details)
#########################################
#                TOKENS                 #
#########################################
AJPS_INT = 'INT'
AJSP_FLOAT = 'FLOAT'
AJSP_PLUS = 'PLUS'
AJSP_MINUS = 'MINUS'
AJSP_MUL = 'MUL'
AJSP_DIV = 'DIV'
AJSP_LPAREN = 'LPAREN'
AJPS_RPAREN = 'RPAREN'
class Token: 
    def __init__(self, type_, value=None):
        self.type = type_
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.value: return f'{self.type}:{self.value}'
        return f'{self.type}'
#########################################
#             LEXING CLASS              #
#########################################
class Lex:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = -1
        self.cchar = None
        self.advance()

    def advance(self):
        self.pos += 1
        self.cchar = self.text[self.pos] if self.pos < len(self.text) else None
    def mtok(self):
        tokens = []
        while self.cchar != None:
            if self.cchar in '\t':
                self.advance()
            elif self.cchar in DIGITS:
                tokens.append(self.make_number())
            elif self.cchar == 'ps':
                tokens.append(Token(AJSP_PLUS))
                self.advance()
            elif self.cchar == 'ms':
                tokens.append(Token(AJSP_MINUS))
                self.advance()
            elif self.cchar == 'my':
                tokens.append(Token(AJSP_MUL))
                self.advance()
            elif self.cchar == 'de':
                tokens.append(Token(AJSP_DIV))
                self.advance()
            elif self.cchar == 'bp':
                tokens.append(Token(AJSP_LPAREN))
                self.advance()
            elif self.cchar == 'ep':
                tokens.append(Token(AJPS_RPAREN))
                self.advance()
            else:
                char = self.cchar
                self.advance()
                return [], unExChar("'" + char + "'")
        return tokens, None
    
    def make_number(self):
        numstr = ''
        dotc = 0
        while self.cchar != None and self.cchar in DIGITS + '.':
            if self.cchar == '.':
                if dotc == 1: break
                dotc += 1
                numstr += '.'
            else:
                numstr += self.cchar
            self.advance()
        
        if dotc == 0:
            return Token(AJPS_INT, int(numstr))
        else:
            return Token(AJPS_FLOAT, float(numstr))

#########################################
#                  RUN                  #
#########################################
def run(text):
    lexer = Lex(text)
    toks, err_ = lexer.mtok()
    return toks, err_
```

My stacktrace is

```
ajsp:> 1 ps 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shell.py", line 4, in <module>
    result, error = ajsp.run(text)
  File "C:\Users\sudo\Desktop\ajsp\ajsp.py", line 102, in run
    toks, err_ = lexer.mtok()
  File "C:\Users\sudo\Desktop\ajsp\ajsp.py", line 77, in mtok
    return [], unExChar("'" + char + "'")
  File "C:\Users\sudo\Desktop\ajsp\ajsp.py", line 17, in __init__
    super().__init__('AJPS DOES NOT UNDERSTAND CHAR AT', details)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Comment: Did you mean to inherit `err` from `unExChar`? `class unExChar(err)`

Comment: Thank you im kinda stupid lmfao

Comment: James already solved your problem, but remeber to start your class names with capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `super()` in your `unExChar` class, which is not a sub-class of another class which you defined.  This means `super` will default to the `object` base class, of which everything is a subclass, but which takes only one argument.

I think you simply forgot to subclass `err`, try:

```
class unExChar(err):
    def __init__(self, details):
        super().__init__('AJPS DOES NOT UNDERSTAND CHAR AT', details)
```

Comment: It's a subclass of `object`, and `object.__init__` doesn't take any additional arguments.

Comment: @chepner, that was what i was attempting to convey.  not too well i guess.  I will clarify.